# Android Button Animation spin 180 degree

Tags: android

I have a simple android project that is a blank activity page with a button at the center . I want when i click on button it spin 180 degree (Like the image matching game when click the button return and the background show ).

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main" tools:context=".MainActivity">
<Button
    android:layout_width="400px"
    android:layout_height="400px"
    android:id="@+id/btn_play"
    android:layout_marginTop="174dp"
    android:background="#001eff"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Sorry for my bad english and my easy question .

Thanks.

Comment: Do post your `onClick` code so far. ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`ObjectAnimator`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html) for this.

```
btn_play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
            {
            ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "rotation", 0, 180).start();
            btn_play.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED)
            }
        });
```

Comment: it just rotate but i want something else , i want when i click on it , see the other side of the button in animation form ( like the image matching games )

Comment: check my edited code.. you need to change your background color

Comment: i know that , my problem is the animation isnt something that i want .let me say an example for you : imagine a paper (my button ) have two page , first i see the first page and then when i spin it i can see the other side of the paper , but the application do it in animation .

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing roation animation

create rotation.xml in res/anim folder:

```
<rotate xmlns:android="”http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android”">
  android:duration="4000"
  android:fromdegrees="0"
  android:pivotx="50%"
  android:pivoty="50%"
  android:todegrees="180"
  android:toyscale="0.0"
</rotate>
```

And in your activity on button click :

```
  btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()    {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
               final Animation animation= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.rotator);


                       animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                           @Override
                           public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                             btn.startAnimation(animation); 
                           }

                           @Override
                           public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                               btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.anotherImage);
                           }

                           @Override
                           public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                           }
                       });


                   }
            }
        });
```

Comment: it just rotate but i want something else , i want when i click on it , see the other side of the button( like the image matching games ).

Comment: @alikhorshidirozbahani Ok then change the button background when it rotates.

Comment: @alikhorshidirozbahani check for answer now.

Comment: now it change the background after that 4s but not doing any animation this time .

Comment: @alikhorshidirozbahani try once more.